# Why are bitwise operators slower than division and modulo in Go?

Tags: go, bitwise-operators

Usually I program in C and frequently use bitwise operators since they are faster. Now I encountered this timing difference by solving Project Euler Problem 14 while using bitwise operators or division and modulo. The program was compiled with `go version go1.6.2`.

Version with bitwise operators:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var buf, longest, cnt, longest_start int    
    

    for i:=2; i<1e6; i++ {
        buf = i
        cnt = 0
        for buf > 1 {
            if (buf & 0x01) == 0 {
                buf >>= 1
            } else {
                buf = buf * 3 + 1
            }
            cnt++
        }
        if cnt > longest {
            longest = cnt
            longest_start = i
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(longest_start)
}
```

executing the program:

```
time ./prob14
837799

real    0m0.300s
user    0m0.301s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Version without bitwise operators (replacing `& 0x01` with `% 2` and `>>= 1` with `/=2`):

```
        for buf > 1 {
            if (buf % 2) == 0 {
                buf /= 2
            } else {
                buf = buf * 3 + 1
            }
            cnt++
        }
```

executing the program:

```
$ time ./prob14 
837799

real    0m0.273s
user    0m0.274s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Why is the version with the bitwise operators in Go slower?

(I also created a solution for the problem in C. Here was the version with the bitwise operators faster without optimization flag (with -O3 they are equal).)

**EDIT**

I did a benchmark as suggested in the comments.

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func Colatz(num int) {
    cnt := 0
    buf := num  

    for buf > 1 {
        if (buf % 2) == 0 {
            buf /= 2
        } else {
            buf = buf * 3 + 1
        }
        cnt++
    }
}

func ColatzBitwise(num int) {
    cnt := 0
    buf := num
    for buf > 1 {
        if (buf & 0x01) == 0 {
            buf >>= 1
        } else {
            buf = buf * 3 + 1
        }
        cnt++
    }
}

func BenchmarkColatz(b *testing.B) {
    for i:=0; i<b.N; i++ {
        Colatz(837799)
    }
}

func BenchmarkColatzBitwise(b *testing.B) {
    for i:=0; i<b.N; i++ {
        ColatzBitwise(837799)
    }
}
```

Here are the benchmark results:

```
go test -bench=.
PASS
BenchmarkColatz-8            2000000           650 ns/op
BenchmarkColatzBitwise-8     2000000           609 ns/op
```

It turns out the bitwise version is faster in the benchmark.

**EDIT 2**

I changed the type of all variables in the functions to `uint`. Here is the benchmark:

```
go test -bench=.
PASS
BenchmarkColatz-8            3000000           516 ns/op
BenchmarkColatzBitwise-8     3000000           590 ns/op
```

The arithmetic version is now faster, as Marc has written in his answer. I will test also with a newer compiler version.

Comment: A ~10% variation on a single run doesn't mean anything. You should write a [benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).

Comment: And Go 1.6 was released more than **4 years ago**. Please, please use a more recent version, as the compiler has gone through many optimizations. Today's compilers recognize dividing or multiplying by 2, and if possible, they generate code that's more efficient, e.g. using bitshifting.

Comment: Microbenchmarks are hard.

Comment: @Volker Can you elaborate why microbenchmarks are hard?

Comment: A modern computer is incredible complicated and modern compilers are incredible sophisticated. It is hard to come up with a microbenchmark that reliably measures what you think it should measure. Microbenchmarks are absolut expert jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they ever were, **they aren't now**.

There are a few problems with your approach:

- you're using go1.6.2 which was **released [over 4 years ago](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#go1.6)**
- you're running a **binary that does other things and running it just once**
- you're **expecting bitshift and arithmetic operations on signed integers to be the same**, they're not

Using go1.15 with micro benchmarks will show the bitwise operations to be faster. The main reason for this is that a bitwise shift and a division by two are **absolutely not the same for signed integers**: the bitwise shift doesn't care about the sign but the division has to preserve it.

If you want to have something closer to equivalent, use unsigned integers for your arithmetic operations, the compiler **may** optimize it to a single bitshift.

In go1.15 on my machine, I see the following being generated for each type of division by 2:

`buf >>=1`:

```
MOVQ AX, DX
SARQ $1, AX
```

`buf /= 2` with `var buf int`:

```
MOVQ AX, DX         
SHRQ $63, AX            
ADDQ DX, AX         
SARQ $1, AX
```

`buf /= 2` with `var buf uint`:

```
MOVQ CX, BX
SHRQ $1, CX
```

Even then, all this must be taken with a large grain of salt: the generated code will depend massively on what else is happening and how the results are used.

But the basic rule applies: **when performing arithmetic operations, the type matters a lot. Bitshift operators don't care about sign**.

Comment: How do you check the generated assembly? (excuse my ignorance ^ ^)

Comment: `go tool objdump <binary>`. I also like the optimizer debugging: `GOSSAFUNC=main go build .` which generates a `ssa.html` file.

Comment: see also https://godbolt.org/z/e8aoqe to explore asm